# Apt-get not working Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: raspbian-stretch, apt, internet

On raspbian stretch:

I set up the raspberry pi to have a static address, so I could use VNC/ssh to access the system rather than needing the separate monitor. Even though I can ssh/VNC into the pi, I am unable to browse the internet or update files or install new packages. I am able to successfully ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com.

The output is:
[image: The error message: 'Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'. As well as for 'archive.raspberrypi.org']

After reading some similar questions, I think I need to either set up a DNS or a proxy, but I am not sure which one is required or what the difference is. I tried to set up the DNS by adding 'server 8.8.8.8' to the  as recommended by this post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=49350. But I just managed to affect the ssh settings so I need to get a monitor before I can continue testing. Also, I was able to ping RaspberryPi.local from my mac to determine the ip address before I added the 'server' line, but that is also not working anymore.

Any recommendations or ideas on how to fix the network connection so I can use apt-get would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You have set a static ip address and you can ping 8.8.8.8. So you have connection the internet  and most things are right. You only need to define a dns server your raspi should use to resolve names e.g. `raspbian.raspberrypi.org`. I don't know how do you set up the static ip address but usually you do it in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. There is a section `# Example static IP configuration`. Uncomment and set:

```
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

These are the name servers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` from google. Be aware that there is a space between them.

Reboot and it should go.

Answer (score 0):

Something you did while setting up your static ip-address probably made the outside internet unavailable to your machine. If you don't know exactly how to undo this,then I would start from a fresh install. That may not be an option, but I don't know.

Do you have a router?

Many routers have a DNS service in them. Mine doesn't, but my NAS does, so I use that. I have my router hand out the IP-addresses, and the NAS serves to connect the names to the addresses.

I have too many machines in a small space for me to remember their numbers.

You can setup a DNS server on a Raspberry Pi for your internal network. I prefer "named," but many prefer avahi instead, though that is more like Bonjour.

Comment: do you want to use avahi because it would help identify the raspberry pi on the network, which allows you to set the wifi as dhcp so the DNS would work?

Comment: You need to have some way of routing the packets. You need DHCP to give ip-numbers to your machines. You don't need to run DNS unless you need name service for your home. It is useful. I don't like avahi, but many people do.